# disable announce_only_user in confbridge

Tags: asterisk, ivr

When first user entered in conference using confbridge, prompt played to user that he is the only person in thee conference room and its due to the default setting in confbridge.conf,
I want to disable this prompt.Anybody can please give me how to disable this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can read confbridge.conf.sample from source tree to see option.

```
;announce_only_user=yes   ; Sets if the only user announcement should be played
                          ; when a channel enters a empty conference.  On by default.
```